# Safe to distribute Google Auth json?

Tags: c#, oauth, google-sheets-api

I am using Google Sheets API to check if user entered data in included in a spreadsheet. The spreadsheet should not be visible to the end user. As far as I can see, you need the Google Auth secret_key.json to access the database. Is this file safe to distribute or does it contains my private info? If not, how might I go about this?

Comment: If you are including the secret key in your application I think you have answered your own question.

Comment: No, it is not safe. Many applications do it, but you shouldn't.

Comment: @PatrickHofman How might I go about this problem?